# Presenting popover from UIBarButtonItem in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I want to present a view controller as an popup in iPhone from a `UIBarButtonItem`

I have written the following piece of code on the action of the button.

```
-(IBAction)showAvailableCategory:(UIButton *)sender
{
    CategoryPopup *categoryPopupViewController = [[CategoryPopup alloc]init];
    UIPopoverPresentationController *popOverCat  = categoryPopupViewController.popoverPresentationController;
    categoryPopupViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(138, 122);
    popOverCat.delegate = self;
    popOverCat.sourceView = sender;
    popOverCat.sourceRect = sender.bounds;
    popOverCat.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
    [self presentViewController:categoryPopupViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I have made my `CategoryPopup` as freeform in the `xib` and also I am implementing the below delegate method

```
-(UIModalPresentationStyle) adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController: (UIPresentationController * ) controller
{
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

But it does not come up as popup rather it comes fullscreen, is there a workaround?

Comment: You need implement your own `UIPresentationController`. Standard `UIPopoverPresentationController` presents popover on iPhone only full screen.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot just one setting, add it right after `categoryPopupViewController`'s initialization:

```
categoryPopupViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
```